# Why integer value gets 0 when the limit is exceeded?

Tags: java

Why an int becomes zero when it exceed the int limit in java?

Eg:

```
import java.util.Scanner
public class MyClass{
public static void main(Stings [] args){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt(); // enter 50 or higher.
int answer = 1;
while(x>0){
answer = answer*x;
x--;
}
System.out.println(answer);
}
}
```

Comment: Uhm... no. That code does not even compile.

Comment: Use [edit] option to correct your example. In current form we can't reproduce problem you are describing as provided code can't even compile.

Comment: `|  Error:
|  integer number too large`

Comment: Sorry I changed the code...... try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point `answer` becomes 0 (integer overflow) and stays 0.